# Testing your site for the heartbleed vulnerability?

Tags: heartbleed

I've seen a number of articles on the heartbleed vulnerability that suggest testing your site to see if it was affecting using Filippo Valsorda's testing page which can be found here:

https://filippo.io/Heartbleed/

When I put the URL to my site into here it says everything is good.  Is this sufficient for determining if one's site is vulnerable or should I be doing something else?

Comment: You can do the same offline (by running `ssltest.py` or Valsorda's `go run bleed.go`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL Labs test will give you the most information about your site, including heartbleed status:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=

This site has worked pretty well for me in testing specifically for heartbleed:
http://possible.lv/tools/hb/

Lastpass uses some other assumptions about previous information to make pretty good guesses:
https://lastpass.com/heartbleed/

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the tests seem to be buggy according to this article here: http://cryptogasm.com/2014/04/whats-worse-than-heartbleed-bugs-in-heartbleed-detection-scripts/

I would rather test it with a script yourself to be sure:
https://gist.github.com/ah8r/10632982

You could compare with the servers of www.cloudflarechallenge.com as a reference. They do heartbleed by intention.